# How to install nodejs socket.io without this Microsoft Visual C++ error?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am getting a very rather annoying error:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\b
in\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build,
please add the "/m" switch.
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it
is installed elsewhere.  [C:\myprog\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\sock
et.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\binding.sln]
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it
is installed elsewhere.  [C:\myprog\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\sock
et.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\binding.sln]
socket.io@1.1.0 node_modules\socket.io
├── debug@0.7.4
├── has-binary-data@0.1.3 (isarray@0.0.1)
├── socket.io-parser@2.2.1 (isarray@0.0.1, component-emitter@1.1.2, benchmark@1.
0.0, json3@3.2.6)
├── socket.io-adapter@0.2.0 (socket.io-parser@2.1.2)
├── engine.io@1.4.0 (base64id@0.1.0, debug@1.0.3, engine.io-parser@1.1.0, ws@0.4
.31)
└── socket.io-client@1.1.0 (to-array@0.1.3, indexof@0.0.1, component-bind@1.0.0,
 object-component@0.0.3, has-binary@0.1.5, component-emitter@1.1.2, socket.io-pa
rser@2.2.2, parseuri@0.0.2, engine.io-client@1.4.0)
```

When I check my Add/remove Programs it looks like I already have:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable
Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable (x64)
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable (x64)
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable (x86)
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable (x86)
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable (x64)
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable (x64)
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1
```

I have Windows 7 64-bit and am running the latest verison of nodejs (v0.10.32) installed from the 64-bit installer. How can I get around this error possibly without installing an entire copy of Visual Studio?

I saw someone mention someplace else `----Instead of compiling the binaries on server, do it on local system.` This is not useful to me at all and I have no clue what to make of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to at least install Visual C++ Express 2010 or newer. I'm not sure if VC++ 2013 is supported by the version of gyp that node/node-gyp ships with. You will also need to install the [Windows 7.0 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138) to compile 64-bit with the Express version of VC++ (although I'm not sure if that is needed for VC++ newer than 2010).

Also, if you install the Express 2012 version that you choose the "for Windows Desktop" edition because there is a separate install for writing Metro applications.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 version is not equivalent/better than the Express version? Also for the Windows 7.0 SDK, the download appears to be 2.5 GB in size... are there required ones I need that could make the total size a bit smaller?

Comment: If you have VC++ 2010 Professional, that will work too. However if you don't want to pay for that, the 2010 Express + SDK combo works fine and is what I'm actually currently using.

Comment: Would VC++ 2012 Professional work (without Windows 7 SDK)? Or must it be the older 2010 version?

Comment: 2012 Professional should work. I've never used anything newer than 2010 (Express) yet, so I'm not sure on the SDK requirement. VS 2012 Professional supposedly comes with Windows 8.0 SDK, but who knows if that means strictly Windows 8.0 or if that also covers Windows 7 also...